# Memcache with Cloudant/Nosql, is it possible?

Tags: node.js, nosql, cloud, ibm-cloud, memcached

Is there a way to use memcached with any nosql database. In my case  in production I have cloudant instance with a near to million users but incur high charges as simply there are more redundant reads than writes. Any thoughts or pointers to using memcache on node.js with any nosql dB will be helpful.